# How to Add DataTable value in DataSet Using every foreach loop in ASP.NET C# Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, webforms

How to Add DataTable value in DataSet Using every foreach loop in ASP.NET C# Webform, Actually I have one gridview and in gridview selected checkbox data should only download to xl.

I have below code for export to xl button.

```
     foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_TotalAllReg.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chk_box")).Checked;
                if (isChecked == true)
                {
                    //var ds = new DataSet();
                    //var dt = new DataTable("RegistrationDetails");

                    int index = row.RowIndex;

                    bo.Para1 = "4";
                    bo.Para2 = "Innovation";

                    bo.Para3 = gv_TotalAllReg.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();//Id



                }
            }
        }
        dt = bl.Admin_GetInnovationbaseonParaType(bo);
        if (gv_TotalAllReg.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dt.TableName = "RegistrationDetails";
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "ApplicationDetails.xls", Page.Response);
            btnExport.Visible = true;


        }
```

Actually base on selected checkbox in gridview that data is not showing in xl sheet, only last selected data is showing in xl sheet.

I am not getting logic `ds.Tables.Add(dt);` to add `dt` values in ds every foreach loop. I need all selected data into xl sheet. Why last select data only coming in xl sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding each row of *datatable* to *dataset* you can add entire *datatable* to *dataset*.

*Dataset* can hold collection of *datatables* so you can add multiple datatable to dataset.

```
DataTable tbl = new Datatable();//or your method that returns datatable.
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); //new dataset object
ds.Tables.Add(tbl); //add datatable object in dataset object.
```

Update

```
 DataTable dt= new DataTable();
//Columns that should present in datatable
dt.Columns.Add("SN");
dt.Columns.Add("MyField");
int sn = 1;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_TotalAllReg.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chk_box")).Checked;
        if (isChecked == true)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            //Add necessary columns to row by index.
            row[0] = sn;
            row[1] = gv_TotalAllReg.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();   
            dt.Rows.Add(row); 
            sn++;
        }
    }
}
if (tbl .Rows.Count > 0)
{
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "ApplicationDetails.xls", Page.Response);
btnExport.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Again its taking last selected data only, can you update full answer according above question. @Bhuban

Comment: can you check my foreach loop logic is correct base on ID i have to get select checkbox data. @Bhuban

Comment: add  dt = bl.Admin_GetInnovationbaseonParaType(bo); inside if (isChecked == true)

I guess dt is DataTable so, you should add row (DataRow) to dt. if dt is Datatable what you are doing right now is creating new Datatable  at the end of foreach using bo. if you take that to inside foreach it will create object everytime so you get exact result but if you add row to datatable you will get all records you want.

Comment: I added but not working please update full answer. @Bhuban

Comment: base on para value executing procedure  bo.Para3 = gv_TotalAllReg.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();//Id values again getting confused and where i have to add this  dt = bl.Admin_GetInnovationbaseonParaType(bo); . @Bhuban

Answer (score 0):

I think you can crete `DataTable` before `foreach` loop, and add rows inside it. Here is an example with adding and retrieving data from `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = bl.Admin_GetInnovationbaseonParaType(bo);
if (gv_TotalAllReg.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     dt.TableName = "RegistrationDetails";
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);               

     foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_TotalAllReg.Rows)
     {
         if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
             bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chk_box")).Checked;
             if (isChecked == true)
             {                    
                // inserting data row
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr.SetField("Column_Name", "your_Value");
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                int index = row.RowIndex;

                bo.Para1 = "4";
                bo.Para2 = "Innovation";

                bo.Para3 = gv_TotalAllReg.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString();//Id
             }
         }
    }

    ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "ApplicationDetails.xls", Page.Response);
    btnExport.Visible = true;
}
```

Retrieving data:

```
string[] values = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Value")).ToArray();
```

Comment: where should have to add this medthod: dt = bl.Admin_GetInnovationbaseonParaType(bo);
        if (gv_TotalAllReg.Rows.Count > 0) . @daniell89

Comment: @mazhar124 -  Updated